# How can I handle PHP response of a dynamic created form such that it is displayed in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've created a dynamic website with an index page that has a container with class 'dynamic_content' in which javascript loads contents based on user input

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/primaryScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/logo.png" id="head"/>
        <div class="dynamic_content">
            <!--content here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

On a certain input, dynamic_content is filled up with a form that has a specific ID registration_form, that manages user inputs by passing them to a server php page with a post action with an input submit.

What I want is that, given any php answer, the response is loaded on the same page, INSIDE dynamic_content, I have tried jQuery with AJAX but it seems that it cannot find the ID of the form, even if I use event handler, this is my jQuery code fragment (my last try with the code found in another answer here):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dynamic_content form").on('submit', function(event) {
    //avoid default behaviour
    event.preventDefault();


    //getting the elements from the form
    var form = $(this);
    var post_url = form.attr('action');
    var post_data = form.serialize();


    //sending data     
    $.post(url, data)
        .done( function(response) {
            $(".dynamic_content").html('<p id="intro">' + data + '</p>');
            $(".dynamic_content").append('<a onclick="index.html"><div class="begin">VAI ALLA HOME</div></a>"');
        })
        .fail( function() {
            alert("The AJAX request failed!");
        });
}); });
```

This code is inside "primaryScript.js".
Is there something wrong? What do I have to do?

Comment: You need to inspect the page and see what is replacing` <!--content here-->` - it could be an iFrame in which case your code certainly will not wrok

Comment: `<a onclick="index.html">` is not a valid construct by the way. You likely meant `<a href="index.html">` and you have weird quotes. Perhaps `'<div class="begin"><a href="index.html">VAI ALLA HOME</a></div>'` ?

Comment: Also you likely want `$(".dynamic_content").on('submit', "form", function(event) {` if the form does not exist on the page at load time

Comment: use $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {
    var myForm = $(this);

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions! The problem by the way is that jQuery cannot find the ID and it is unique, so the php answer is given on a new refreshed page (the function in jQuery is not considered at all)